# Warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040', why not '\x20'?

Tags: c, bash, escaping

When I compile a C file has contents below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILE_NAME "text\ 1"

int main()
{
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
    fclose(file_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

get warning:

```
tt.c: In function ‘main’:
tt.c:6:37: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040'
    6 |     FILE* file_ptr = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
      |
```

I know it caused by `\`  in a string of my C language code and `40` is decimal `32` as ASCII of SPACE. **Why the warning** is `'\040'` not `'\x20'`?

And seems also in bash `\`  transfer to `\040` seed to binaries (not sure).

Is there a rule to force it?

---

Update：delete '\32' which used to represent ASCII of SPACE to decimal.

---

**How I encounter this problem?**

I just wanna know how Bash process ESCAPED SPACE, I thougt bash turn it to SPACE, but after I check source code of Bash (hard for me). I found maybe Bash treat `\`  as normal string of characters as below source code not involved `\` :

```
#define slashify_in_quotes "\\`$\"\n"
#define slashify_in_here_document "\\`$"

#define shell_meta_chars   "()<>;&|"
#define shell_break_chars  "()<>;&| \t\n"

#define shell_quote_chars   "\"`'"
```

So I think Bash turn the `\`  to the command or binary to process, so I write above simple C file to check how C treat `\`

---

So my question is Why gcc warning `'\040'` not `'\x20'`?

For how Bash treat `\`  still need me to check...

Comment: I don't think `\32` is a valid escape sequence scenario.

Comment: [ideone](https://ideone.com/O9Pgoz) does not agree with you :-)

Comment: `'\32'` is one representation of character with integer code `26` (octal `32`).

Comment: In C, the numbers after a backslash are octal (1-3 digits in the range 0..7).  It can be written in hex with backslash-x, in which case as many hex digits as possible are read.   The character constants `'\040'` and `'\x20'` are equivalent; the choice of notation is yours (and `' '` also works on most, but not all, machines).  There is no option to express the number after the backslash in decimal.  The designers of C didn't think there was a need/benefit to doing so.

Comment: In many ways, your question is not clear.  Where is the message "unknown escape sequence" being generated?  Is it in a shell script or in C source code?  Are you using the Bash [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism?  It would help a lot if you showed the code and context in which you're running into the problem.

Comment: `'\040'` has an advantage over `'\x20'` when part of a _string_.  `"\040123"` is like `" 123"`.   `"\x20123"` is a problem as the hexadecimal-escape-sequence is not clear.

Comment: Why do you think `\040` is not the same as `\x20`? When I run `#include <stdio.h>` / `int main(void) { printf("%d\n", '\040' == '\x20'); }`, it prints “1”, showing they are the same.

Comment: Hi, @EricPostpischil I just wonder why the warning use `'\040'` not `'\x20'`?

Comment: roachsinai, "why the warning use '\040' not '\x20'" --> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037628/warning-unknown-escape-sequence-040-why-not-x20#comment114981105_65037628)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Wrong. See C11: 6.4.4.4 Character constants - 7: _Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can
constitute the escape sequence._ `"\040123"` escapes the character U+4053 or `'䁓'`, assuming you use a wide string literal or have `CHAR_BIT>=15` and use Unicode. You get UB where `char` is 8 bit signed and `0x53` where `char` is 8 bit unsigned`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037628/warning-unknown-escape-sequence-040-why-not-x20?noredirect=1#comment114981105_65037628), the hex esc seq  is a problem.  Good to see you have pointed out some of the problems.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, but both have the same problem. Octal AND hexadecimal escape sequences are as long as they possible can, according to C11.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Octal escape sequences are linted to 3 digits.  hex esc seq are not limited.  `"\040123"` is not a problem.  See 6.4.4.4 _octal-escape-sequence_ vs. _hexadecimal-escape-sequence_.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to Updated Question

> Why the warning is '\040' not '\x20'?

This is merely a choice by the compiler implementors. When you have `\` in a string or character constant followed by something that is not a recognized escape sequence, the compiler warns you. For example, if you had `\g`, the compiler would warn you that `\g` is not recognized. When the character after the `\` may be unclear, because it is a white space character that cannot be distinguished from others (like space from tab) or is not a printable character, the compiler shows it by value in the error message. This helps you find the exact character in your text editor, in case some unprintable character has slipped into the source code. The compiler authors could have used hexadecimal but simply chose to use octal.

I will fault them for using an inconsistent style. In GCC 10.2, `\g` results in the message `unknown escape sequence: '\g'`, but `\`  results in the message `unknown escape sequence: '\040'`. These should either be:

- `unknown escape sequence: 'g'` and `unknown escape sequence: '\040'` or
- `unknown escape sequence: '\g'` and `unknown escape sequence: '\\040'`.

### Answer to Original Vague Question

C 2018 6.4.4.4 specific character constants in C source code, and paragraph 1 lists four choices for *escape-sequence*: *simple-escape-sequence*, *octal-escape-sequence*, *hexdecimal-escape-sequence*, and *univesal-char-name*.

An *octal-escape-sequence* is `\` followed by one to three octal digits. Thus, `\040` the character with code 040<sub>8</sub> = 32, and `\32` is the character with code 32<sub>8</sub> = 26.

There is no decimal escape sequence; `\32` is an octal escape sequence, not decimal. (Also note that because octal escape sequences can have various lengths, if one wishes to follow it by an octal digit, one must use all three allowed digits. `\324` will be parsed as one character, not as `\32` followed by `4`, whereas `\0324` is `\032` followed by `4`.)

A *hexadecimal-escape-sequence* is `\x` followed by any positive integer number of hexadecimal digits. `\x20` is equal to `\040`.

(A *simple-escape-sequence* is one of `\'`, `\"`, `\?`, `\\`, `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, or `\v`. A *universal-character-name* is `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits or `\U` followed by eight hexadecimal digits.)